# MacOs pip3 not installing ansible binary

Tags: macos, ansible

I cannot locate an ansible binary to run and add to my path. Finally, it looks like pip3/pip is not actually installing it. Lots of dependencies, but not the binary to run.

what's the best way to force this? do I need to uninstall pip?

Had 2.9 running and then like an idiot broke it. I'm not using brew. Running BigSur.

Answer (score 0):

Wiped all references to ansible. Deleted the cache. Reinstalled with pip and it worked.